# Git Install as User?

Tags: git, compilation, makefile, bsd, netbsd

I am trying to install git as a user on a netbsd system (4.0.1_PATCH) by compiling git 1.8.0 from source using the source tarball from github. I have user privileges on this system but do not have root privileges. I am compiling the source code in my home directory.

I am now getting this set of error messages:

```
gmake                                                                                                                                                                    ~/src/git-git-fe1bdde
GIT_VERSION = 1.8.0
    * new build flags
    CC credential-store.o
    * new link flags
    CC abspath.o
    CC advice.o
    CC alias.o
    CC alloc.o
    CC archive.o
    CC archive-tar.o
In file included from run-command.h:5,
                 from archive-tar.c:8:
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:285: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:71: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:286: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_attr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:72: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_attr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:288: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_once_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:77: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_once_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:289: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_mutexattr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:74: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_mutexattr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:290: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_mutex_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:73: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_mutex_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:291: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_condattr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:76: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_condattr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:292: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_cond_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:75: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_cond_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:293: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_rwlockattr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:80: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_rwlockattr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:294: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_rwlock_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:79: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_rwlock_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:357: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_kill'
/usr/include/signal.h:69: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_kill' was here
gmake: *** [archive-tar.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong and how to correct this?

Any suggestion on installing git as user on netbsd (version 4.0.1 which I believe is fairly old)?

Comment: Did you install pthread yourself as well?

Comment: The easiest solution is to ask your admin.

Comment: Did you run the `make configure; ./configure --<bla>; make; ...` dance as instructed by `INSTALL`? BSD is sufficiently different from Linux that the default configuration might not work.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t compile it yourself!

Instead, use NetBSD® pkgsrc® as nōn-root, which is not only possible but perfectly well supported: [It’s even a FAQ](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/faq.html#non-root-pkgsrc)

This will save you a lot of hassle because it’ll take care of automatically installing the dependencies *and* patch the software so it works on BSD.